# How to host multiple static sites on s3 through CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have multiple static sites, each bundled with one index.html file, and each one lives in its own s3 bucket, so my list of buckets would look something like:

```
site-version-1
    page-1.js
    page-2.js
    index.html
site-version-2
    page-1.js
    page-2.js
    index.html
```

Where `site-version-1` and `site-version-2` are both origins of my CloudFront distribution. I would like to be able to visit `http://cloudfront-url/site-version-1/page-1` and `http://cloudfront-url-site-version-2/page-1` and have those pages be correlated with their appropriate bundles, but I'm a bit stuck as to how I would correlate the name of the bucket with a page under the distribution, if that's directly possible at all.

I've also tried having everything in the same bucket, but in different folders--so that bucket looked like:

```
bucket
    site-version-1
        page-1.js
        page-2.js
        index.html
    site-version-2
        page-1.js
        page-2.js
        index.html
```

In this case, when I visit the CloudFront url followed by the name of the folder, it wouldn't know which page I was trying to view.

Comment: What do you mean by "be correlated with their appropriate bundles"? And what do you mean by "it wouldn't know which page I was trying to view"? Can you be more specific about what you are doing and what result you are receiving? For example, when you tried "everything in the same bucket", what URL did you try, and what did you receive back?

Comment: By "correlated with their appropriate bundles," I meant that when I visit the url "http://cloudfront-url/site-version-1/page-1" I would want to see page-1.js that's hosted in site-version-1, and when I visit "http://cloudfront-url/site-version-2/page-1" I would want to see page-1.js that's hosted in site-version2. 

I have a generic error page that comes up from my site when a user tries to navigate to a page that doesn't exist, and I'm getting that page when I visit either of those URLs that I mentioned above--will finish my response in another comment since I'm running out of characters:)

Comment: When I put both versions in the one bucket as opposed to having the two versions in two different buckets, I was using that bucket as the one origin for the same cloudfront distribution (so, url "http://cloudfront-url"), but that base url doesn't load since it's missing an index.html file, and if i append one of the bucket names to the url, it shows that error page that I mentioned above since it doesn't recognize the page I'm trying to view.